# how to make JSON.stringify encode UTF characters

Tags: javascript, json, encode, utf, stringify

I'm writing a JS that run using windows `cscript.exe`.
My JS is loading JSON object from file, adds a parameter and saves it back to file (using json2.min.js implementation).

I'm using `JSON.parse(text)` to parse the text into JSON object, and then `JSON.stringify(text, null, 3)` to create the string that I'm writing back. Everything works great until I encounter Unicode encoding.

In the file there are certain values such as

```
"someKey": "\u003Ca href=\"http://www.something.com\"\u003E"
```

that after I read and save back to file (`stringify`) are changed into:

```
"someKey": "< a href=\"http://www.something.com\">
```

There are a few other foreign Unicode characters that are converted.

**How can I keep the original encoding when I perform `stringify`?**

**Is there any conversion function that I can use during `stringify` or apply after?**

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not binary safe so avoid it.

There are some binary-safe JSON-like implementations: check BISON at http://kaijaeger.com/articles/introducing-bison-binary-interchange-standard.html